# Does GraphQL allow for objects without an identifier (ID)

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I understand that GraphQL allows for object identifiers (ID) to uniquely identify objects in an object graph. This allows queries to return one or more "identifiable" objects. Frameworks such as Apollo even make use of these identifiers (along with `__typename`) to build a smart cache.

However, what about the scenario where we want to return an object that is not identifiable, e.g. the result of a computation. For example, the following query returns
the count of repositories by language type:

```
const GET_REPO_COUNTS = gql`
  query GetRepoCounts {
    repoCounts {
      language
      count
    }
  }
`;
```

The response is something like this:

```
{
  repoCounts: [
    {
      language: 'javascript',
      repoCount: 10
    },
    {
      language: 'typescript',
      repoCount: 20
    }
  ]
}
```

The returned objects don't have any "identity". In DDD terms, they are simply value objects.

1. Does GraphQL specifically allow or disallow such scenarios?
2. How do frameworks like Apollo deal with it? Is this something that is cached on the client side? How?

Comment: 'custom json scalar' or define type key fields to language